# JasperReport concatenation only prints the first report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to concatenate two reports with JasperReports, I've a list with two jasperPrints from the report "A" and report "B". The problem is that it's only printing the first report, the second page is empty. I though that the problem was in report "B" but if I print first the report "B" I've the same problem: the report "B" is printed and the second page that should be the report "A" is empty.

Here is my code:

```
public static InputStream generatePdfByteArrayFromJasper(List<InputStream> reportStreams, Collection dataSource, HashMap<String, Object> parameters)
throws JRException {
    List<JasperPrint> jasperPrints = new ArrayList<>();
    JRDataSource datasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataSource, true);
    for (InputStream is : reportStreams) {
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(is, parameters, datasource);
        jasperPrints.add(jasperPrint);
    }
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput exporterOutput = new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(out);
    SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
    configuration.setCreatingBatchModeBookmarks(true);
    exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
    exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(jasperPrints));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(exporterOutput);
    exporter.exportReport();
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
}
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the same data source object for both reports.  The data source get consumed by the first report, and there will be no records left for the second report.

What you should do is create e data source instance for each report.  And it's a good idea to do the same thing with the parameters map, because the fill process populates builtin parameters into the map and there is a risk that a parameter set by the first report would end up being used for the second report.

So the code would look something like this:

```
public static InputStream generatePdfByteArrayFromJasper(List<InputStream> reportStreams, Collection dataSource, HashMap<String, Object> parameters)
throws JRException {
    List<JasperPrint> jasperPrints = new ArrayList<>();
    for (InputStream is : reportStreams) {
        JRDataSource datasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataSource, true);
        HashMap<String, Object> reportParameters = new HashMap<>(parameters);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(is, reportParameters, datasource);
        jasperPrints.add(jasperPrint);
    }
```